# If I have the Aberrant Dragonmark feat and get the Boon of Spell Mastery at 10th level, can I choose the spell I learned from the feat for the boon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, boons

I'm playing a variant human fighter with the Aberrant Dragonmark feat who just hit level 10.

The Aberrant Dragonmark feat lets me choose a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer spell list and cast it through my dragonmark. The Greater Aberrant Powers optional rule for the feat also grants a chance to gain an epic boon when I reach level 10; I received the Boon of Spell Mastery.

Can I choose the 1st-level spell I learned from my Aberrant Dragonmark for the Boon of Spell Mastery to apply to?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: It works but you already get that spell on a short rest, so it seems like a waste to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, that works.

The description of the [Boon of Spell Mastery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards#EpicBoons) says (DMG, p. 232):

> Choose one 1st-level sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell that you can cast. [...]

The description of the [Aberrant Dragonmark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/aberrant-dragonmark) says, in part (E:RftLW, p. 52; WGtE, p. 112):

> - In addition, choose a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer spell list. You learn that spell and can cast it through your mark. [...]

So since you can cast a sorcerer spell, that spell is a valid choice for the Boon of Spell Mastery.